# Subnetting help and confusion

Tags: subnet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Subnetting Work?](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-subnetting-work)

I am a bit confused, I have been given an address 132.132.0.0/16 and i have to devise a scheme allowing for at least 396 subnets. I think i have to extend the subnet mask to do this, I have worked through the different possible masks and the mask /25 gives me a possible 512 subnets this fits into the criteria i was to use. As there is 9 bits left, to find the number of hosts per subnet mask I use the formula 2^9 = 128 hosts, so the first address for the subnet mask 0 is

Subnet 0 - 132.132.0.0, address range is 132.132.0.1 - 132.132.0.126 and the broadcast is 132.132.0.127

Subnet 1 - 132.132.0.128, address range is 132.132.0.129 - 132.132.0.254 and the broadcast is 132.132.0.255

Subnet 2 - 132.132.1.0, address range is 132.132.1.1 - 132.132.1.126 and the broadcast is 132.132.1.127

Subnet 350 - If I know it takes two subnets to fill the 4th octet, do i just take 350 - 1 (cause we start at subnet 0) which gives us 349/2 which gives us 174.5 so the  address id would be 132.132.174.128 and the address range would be 132.132.174.129 - 132.132.174.254 and the broadcast is 132.132.175.255

Is this correct?

Thank you

Comment: Read here: http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-subnetting-work

Answer (score 0):

```
Network           Net Broadcast     CIDR Mask              UsableHosts
132.132.0.0       132.132.31.255    19   255.255.224.0     8,190       Available
132.132.32.0      132.132.47.255    20   255.255.240.0     4,094       Available
132.132.48.0      132.132.55.255    21   255.255.248.0     2,046       Available
132.132.56.0      132.132.57.255    23   255.255.254.0     510         Available
132.132.58.0      132.132.58.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.58.128    132.132.58.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.59.0      132.132.59.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.59.128    132.132.59.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.60.0      132.132.60.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.60.128    132.132.60.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.61.0      132.132.61.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.61.128    132.132.61.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.62.0      132.132.62.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.62.128    132.132.62.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.63.0      132.132.63.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.63.128    132.132.63.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.64.0      132.132.64.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.64.128    132.132.64.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.65.0      132.132.65.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.65.128    132.132.65.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.66.0      132.132.66.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.66.128    132.132.66.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.67.0      132.132.67.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.67.128    132.132.67.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.68.0      132.132.68.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.68.128    132.132.68.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.69.0      132.132.69.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.69.128    132.132.69.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.70.0      132.132.70.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.70.128    132.132.70.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.71.0      132.132.71.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.71.128    132.132.71.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.72.0      132.132.72.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.72.128    132.132.72.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.73.0      132.132.73.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.73.128    132.132.73.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.74.0      132.132.74.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.74.128    132.132.74.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.75.0      132.132.75.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.75.128    132.132.75.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.76.0      132.132.76.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.76.128    132.132.76.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.77.0      132.132.77.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.77.128    132.132.77.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.78.0      132.132.78.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.78.128    132.132.78.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.79.0      132.132.79.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.79.128    132.132.79.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.80.0      132.132.80.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.80.128    132.132.80.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.81.0      132.132.81.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.81.128    132.132.81.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.82.0      132.132.82.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.82.128    132.132.82.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.83.0      132.132.83.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.83.128    132.132.83.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.84.0      132.132.84.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.84.128    132.132.84.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.85.0      132.132.85.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.85.128    132.132.85.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.86.0      132.132.86.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.86.128    132.132.86.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.87.0      132.132.87.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.87.128    132.132.87.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.88.0      132.132.88.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.88.128    132.132.88.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.89.0      132.132.89.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.89.128    132.132.89.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.90.0      132.132.90.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.90.128    132.132.90.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.91.0      132.132.91.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.91.128    132.132.91.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.92.0      132.132.92.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.92.128    132.132.92.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.93.0      132.132.93.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.93.128    132.132.93.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.94.0      132.132.94.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.94.128    132.132.94.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.95.0      132.132.95.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.95.128    132.132.95.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.96.0      132.132.96.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.96.128    132.132.96.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.97.0      132.132.97.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.97.128    132.132.97.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.98.0      132.132.98.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.98.128    132.132.98.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.99.0      132.132.99.127    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.99.128    132.132.99.255    25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.100.0     132.132.100.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.100.128   132.132.100.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.101.0     132.132.101.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.101.128   132.132.101.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.102.0     132.132.102.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.102.128   132.132.102.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.103.0     132.132.103.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.103.128   132.132.103.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.104.0     132.132.104.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.104.128   132.132.104.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.105.0     132.132.105.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.105.128   132.132.105.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.106.0     132.132.106.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.106.128   132.132.106.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.107.0     132.132.107.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.107.128   132.132.107.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.108.0     132.132.108.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.108.128   132.132.108.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.109.0     132.132.109.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.109.128   132.132.109.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.110.0     132.132.110.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.110.128   132.132.110.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.111.0     132.132.111.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.111.128   132.132.111.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.112.0     132.132.112.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.112.128   132.132.112.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.113.0     132.132.113.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.113.128   132.132.113.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.114.0     132.132.114.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.114.128   132.132.114.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.115.0     132.132.115.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.115.128   132.132.115.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.116.0     132.132.116.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.116.128   132.132.116.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.117.0     132.132.117.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.117.128   132.132.117.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.118.0     132.132.118.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.118.128   132.132.118.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.119.0     132.132.119.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.119.128   132.132.119.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.120.0     132.132.120.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.120.128   132.132.120.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.121.0     132.132.121.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.121.128   132.132.121.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.122.0     132.132.122.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.122.128   132.132.122.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.123.0     132.132.123.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.123.128   132.132.123.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.124.0     132.132.124.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.124.128   132.132.124.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.125.0     132.132.125.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.125.128   132.132.125.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.126.0     132.132.126.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.126.128   132.132.126.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.127.0     132.132.127.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.127.128   132.132.127.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.128.0     132.132.128.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.128.128   132.132.128.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.129.0     132.132.129.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.129.128   132.132.129.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.130.0     132.132.130.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.130.128   132.132.130.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.131.0     132.132.131.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.131.128   132.132.131.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.132.0     132.132.132.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.132.128   132.132.132.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.133.0     132.132.133.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.133.128   132.132.133.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.134.0     132.132.134.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.134.128   132.132.134.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.135.0     132.132.135.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.135.128   132.132.135.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.136.0     132.132.136.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.136.128   132.132.136.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.137.0     132.132.137.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.137.128   132.132.137.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.138.0     132.132.138.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.138.128   132.132.138.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.139.0     132.132.139.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.139.128   132.132.139.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.140.0     132.132.140.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.140.128   132.132.140.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.141.0     132.132.141.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.141.128   132.132.141.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.142.0     132.132.142.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.142.128   132.132.142.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.143.0     132.132.143.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.143.128   132.132.143.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.144.0     132.132.144.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.144.128   132.132.144.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.145.0     132.132.145.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.145.128   132.132.145.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.146.0     132.132.146.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.146.128   132.132.146.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.147.0     132.132.147.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.147.128   132.132.147.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.148.0     132.132.148.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.148.128   132.132.148.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.149.0     132.132.149.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.149.128   132.132.149.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.150.0     132.132.150.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.150.128   132.132.150.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.151.0     132.132.151.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.151.128   132.132.151.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.152.0     132.132.152.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.152.128   132.132.152.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.153.0     132.132.153.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.153.128   132.132.153.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.154.0     132.132.154.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.154.128   132.132.154.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.155.0     132.132.155.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.155.128   132.132.155.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.156.0     132.132.156.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.156.128   132.132.156.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.157.0     132.132.157.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.157.128   132.132.157.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.158.0     132.132.158.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.158.128   132.132.158.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.159.0     132.132.159.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.159.128   132.132.159.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.160.0     132.132.160.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.160.128   132.132.160.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.161.0     132.132.161.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.161.128   132.132.161.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.162.0     132.132.162.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.162.128   132.132.162.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.163.0     132.132.163.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.163.128   132.132.163.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.164.0     132.132.164.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.164.128   132.132.164.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.165.0     132.132.165.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.165.128   132.132.165.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.166.0     132.132.166.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.166.128   132.132.166.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.167.0     132.132.167.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.167.128   132.132.167.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.168.0     132.132.168.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.168.128   132.132.168.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.169.0     132.132.169.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.169.128   132.132.169.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.170.0     132.132.170.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.170.128   132.132.170.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.171.0     132.132.171.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.171.128   132.132.171.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.172.0     132.132.172.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.172.128   132.132.172.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.173.0     132.132.173.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.173.128   132.132.173.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.174.0     132.132.174.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.174.128   132.132.174.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.175.0     132.132.175.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.175.128   132.132.175.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.176.0     132.132.176.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.176.128   132.132.176.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.177.0     132.132.177.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.177.128   132.132.177.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.178.0     132.132.178.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.178.128   132.132.178.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.179.0     132.132.179.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.179.128   132.132.179.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.180.0     132.132.180.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.180.128   132.132.180.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.181.0     132.132.181.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.181.128   132.132.181.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.182.0     132.132.182.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.182.128   132.132.182.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.183.0     132.132.183.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.183.128   132.132.183.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.184.0     132.132.184.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.184.128   132.132.184.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.185.0     132.132.185.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.185.128   132.132.185.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.186.0     132.132.186.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.186.128   132.132.186.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.187.0     132.132.187.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.187.128   132.132.187.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.188.0     132.132.188.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.188.128   132.132.188.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.189.0     132.132.189.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.189.128   132.132.189.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.190.0     132.132.190.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.190.128   132.132.190.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.191.0     132.132.191.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.191.128   132.132.191.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.192.0     132.132.192.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.192.128   132.132.192.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.193.0     132.132.193.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.193.128   132.132.193.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.194.0     132.132.194.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.194.128   132.132.194.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.195.0     132.132.195.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.195.128   132.132.195.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.196.0     132.132.196.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.196.128   132.132.196.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.197.0     132.132.197.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.197.128   132.132.197.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.198.0     132.132.198.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.198.128   132.132.198.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.199.0     132.132.199.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.199.128   132.132.199.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.200.0     132.132.200.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.200.128   132.132.200.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.201.0     132.132.201.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.201.128   132.132.201.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.202.0     132.132.202.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.202.128   132.132.202.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.203.0     132.132.203.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.203.128   132.132.203.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.204.0     132.132.204.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.204.128   132.132.204.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.205.0     132.132.205.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.205.128   132.132.205.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.206.0     132.132.206.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.206.128   132.132.206.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.207.0     132.132.207.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.207.128   132.132.207.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.208.0     132.132.208.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.208.128   132.132.208.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.209.0     132.132.209.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.209.128   132.132.209.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.210.0     132.132.210.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.210.128   132.132.210.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.211.0     132.132.211.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.211.128   132.132.211.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.212.0     132.132.212.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.212.128   132.132.212.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.213.0     132.132.213.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.213.128   132.132.213.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.214.0     132.132.214.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.214.128   132.132.214.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.215.0     132.132.215.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.215.128   132.132.215.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.216.0     132.132.216.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.216.128   132.132.216.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.217.0     132.132.217.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.217.128   132.132.217.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.218.0     132.132.218.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.218.128   132.132.218.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.219.0     132.132.219.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.219.128   132.132.219.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.220.0     132.132.220.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.220.128   132.132.220.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.221.0     132.132.221.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.221.128   132.132.221.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.222.0     132.132.222.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.222.128   132.132.222.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.223.0     132.132.223.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.223.128   132.132.223.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.224.0     132.132.224.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.224.128   132.132.224.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.225.0     132.132.225.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.225.128   132.132.225.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.226.0     132.132.226.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.226.128   132.132.226.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.227.0     132.132.227.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.227.128   132.132.227.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.228.0     132.132.228.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.228.128   132.132.228.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.229.0     132.132.229.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.229.128   132.132.229.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.230.0     132.132.230.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.230.128   132.132.230.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.231.0     132.132.231.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.231.128   132.132.231.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.232.0     132.132.232.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.232.128   132.132.232.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.233.0     132.132.233.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.233.128   132.132.233.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.234.0     132.132.234.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.234.128   132.132.234.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.235.0     132.132.235.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.235.128   132.132.235.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.236.0     132.132.236.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.236.128   132.132.236.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.237.0     132.132.237.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.237.128   132.132.237.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.238.0     132.132.238.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.238.128   132.132.238.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.239.0     132.132.239.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.239.128   132.132.239.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.240.0     132.132.240.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.240.128   132.132.240.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.241.0     132.132.241.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.241.128   132.132.241.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.242.0     132.132.242.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.242.128   132.132.242.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.243.0     132.132.243.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.243.128   132.132.243.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.244.0     132.132.244.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.244.128   132.132.244.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.245.0     132.132.245.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.245.128   132.132.245.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.246.0     132.132.246.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.246.128   132.132.246.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.247.0     132.132.247.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.247.128   132.132.247.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.248.0     132.132.248.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.248.128   132.132.248.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.249.0     132.132.249.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.249.128   132.132.249.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.250.0     132.132.250.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.250.128   132.132.250.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.251.0     132.132.251.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.251.128   132.132.251.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.252.0     132.132.252.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.252.128   132.132.252.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.253.0     132.132.253.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.253.128   132.132.253.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.254.0     132.132.254.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.254.128   132.132.254.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.255.0     132.132.255.127   25   255.255.255.128   126
132.132.255.128   132.132.255.255   25   255.255.255.128   126
```